# How to have a CommandObject wait for a specific Task to complete when the task was kicked off from a separate view?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvvmcross

I've got a situation where An activity kicks off an async task (to synchronize data with the server) and then navigates to a login view. If the user is "too quick" to log in, the app crashes with a `ForeignKeyException` because some of the records from the async task don't exist yet in the local database.

I want the user to be taken to the login screen quickly, but I still need to wait for the Task that was kicked off in the `MvxApplication.Initialize()` method before triggering the login code.

Essentially like this

1. App First Launches
   `MvxActivity.Initialize() {
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() = > new SyncEngine().TwoWaySync());
       RegisterAppStart<AuthViewModel>();
   }`
2. Then AuthViewModel is quickly displayed to the user, all the while, the `SyncEngine().TwoWaySync()` task is still running.
3. User fills in the form and clicks the [Login] button.
4. ***App must wait for the `SyncEngine().TwoWaySync()` task to complete before executing the `LoginCommand()`.***

Since we're using MvvmCross, do we use the Messenger Plugin to notify when the task is complete, or should we implement some form of Thread Queueing? If it's Thread Queueing, what's the right way to approach this in a PCL?

Comment: The normal way to do this is to use `ContinueWith` or to use `await`. Generally you will do this in some application level class - some singleton service which both views know about. One challenge here can be working out how this service is kept alive across the application being put into the background and/or tombstoned - but this isn't unique to mvvm or mvvmcross - it's normal app development.